# How can I add data to SQLite tables as foreign keys?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have two tables in my database. Those are `user` and `message`.

`User` table contains with,

1. Userid (Primary key)
2. UserName
3. Password columns

`Message` table contains with,

1. MessageId (Primary Key)
2. Userid (Foreign key)
3. Subject
4. Message columns

After login user can send a message. So I want to save the above column details in the `message` table. But when I fill the table, `userid` is not getting as a foreign key. That column is empty like the following image.

[image]

These are my dbHandler code

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String TABLE_USER_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+ UserTable.Users.TABLE_NAME+"("+
            UserTable.Users._ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+
            UserTable.Users.COLUMN_NAME+" TEXT,"+
            UserTable.Users.COLUMN_PASSWORD+ " TEXT,"+
            UserTable.Users.COLUMN_TYPE+ " TEXT"+" );";
    db.execSQL(TABLE_USER_CREATE);

    String TABLE_MESSAGE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+ MessageTable.Messages.TABLE_NAME+"("+
            MessageTable.Messages._ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+
            MessageTable.Messages.COLUMN_USER+" TEXT,"+
            MessageTable.Messages.COLUMN_SUBJECT+ " TEXT,"+
            MessageTable.Messages.COLUMN_MESSAGE+" TEXT,"+
            " FOREIGN KEY ("+ MessageTable.Messages.COLUMN_USER+") REFERENCES "+ UserTable.Users.TABLE_NAME+"("+ UserTable.Users._ID+"))";
    db.execSQL(TABLE_MESSAGE_CREATE);
}
```

Save message Method:

```
 public long saveMessage(String subjects, String messages){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MessageTable.Messages.COLUMN_SUBJECT,subjects);
    contentValues.put(MessageTable.Messages.COLUMN_MESSAGE,messages);

   long newRowId = db.insert(MessageTable.Messages.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);

    db.close();
    return newRowId; }
```

I'm new to android. Can somebody help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's `NULL` because you never set it. Foreign keys aren't magic, they're just a constraint that whatever value you add must be present in the referenced column.

As you also didn't add a `NOT NULL` constraint, it just adds exactly what you told it to - only the subject and message.